# How to use ANT to save current process run time?

Tags: ant

How to save current process running time in some text file using Ant, then read file and assign to Ant variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ant exec task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html). There you can specify the executable `ps` and the necessary arguments (PID, options). You can check the argumengs [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7870/how-to-check-how-long-a-process-has-been-running).

You specify `outputproperty` in ant exec task so the output will be redirected to this property.

Then you can put the value in a file using the [echo task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html).

Comment: using this how will I get current process run time?Can you please elaborate more on this and If you have sample code for this, can you please share?

Comment: @Rohit Patil Was my anwwer useful? If you up-vote and accept useful answers people will be more motivated to help you